# Adding scroll bars to a listview using JqueryMobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

Trying to add scrollbars to a listview within a dialog in JQueryMobile with no joy.

I'm using the following code:

```
            <div class="content-primary">
            <ul id="lvPages" data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-inset="true" data-scroll="true"></ul>
        </div>
```

Which works perfect on desktop browsers yet when I test this on an iPad the scrollbars don't appear.

Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Sorry, should actually add:

I'm adding the items via Javascript and am calling a " $("#lvPages").listview('refresh');" upon the end of these additions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this forum article](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/is-data-scroll-true-active-in-jquery-mobile), you have to include the `jquery.mobile.scrollview.js` script (and its associated CSS file) for the `data-scroll` attribute to be recognized and acted upon.

Comment: Thanks, eventually got 'something' working so I think I'm on the right track.